# Loop iterator offset

Tags: c#, for-loop

Let's say I've an array of 4 items.

When I access the first index, I would also like to access an offset of -1 (in this case, it would loop to 3)

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
  int item = array[i];

  int offset = 0;
  if (i == 0)
  {
    offset = array.Length -1;
  }
  else 
  {
    offset = i -1;
  }
  int offsetItem = array[offset];
}
```

Is there a more elegant way of achieving this? I keep thinking of using the modulo operator, but I don't understand it well enough to know if its the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Add the length of the array to the index, and use remainder operator, like this:

```
int offset = (i-1+array.Length) % array.Length;
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out I can also do `(i-1) % array.Length;` Works out the same!

Comment: @MHTri You need to add `array.Length`, otherwise it will produce `-1` when `i` is zero.

Comment: But that's fine surely, because -1 % 4 = 3, which is the end of a zero-indexed array.

Comment: No, `-1 %4 = -1`. You need to add 4 as well.

Comment: @MHTri I don't know how you get `3` from `-1 % 4`, it produces `-1` for me ([demo](http://ideone.com/mWI9Lx)).

Comment: Ah, I see now, in C-based languages % is a remainder operator, not modulus. I was doing some quick calculations in Google Calculator.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot define variable i within the loop as i has already been defined.

```
  for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
           int j = array[i];  
           int offset = (j == 0)?(array.Length -1):( i -1);    
           int offsetItem = array[offset];
  }
```

Comment: Whoops, fixed. Thanks!